# How to check if a vlues lays within a specific range of values

Tags: javascript, ava

I am using ava testingUnit and I want to know how to check if the value i receive is within a specific range. For example, I have a method that shuffles
an array and picks an item from that array randomly. Let's consider that example,

the method might return

```
[4,5,1] OR [4,5,2] OR [4,5,3]
```

In other words, I would like to know how to check if the value i receive from that method is either on eof the following values:

```
[4,5,1] OR [4,5,2] OR [4,5,3]
```

What I want to do do is, to check if the the returned value is either one of the aforementioned values??

Thanks

Comment: Could you re-phrase your question a little? E.g. what does the range and the value look like.

Comment: @SalmanA i have already rephrased the question

Comment: `[4,5,3].indexOf(4)` and `[4,5,3].indexOf(9999)`?

Comment: @SalmanA would you please clarify how to use what have you suggested in "ava" unitTest??!!

Comment: sorry no idea about ava. But something like `t.true([4,5,1].indexOf(someValue) >= 0)` should pass if `someValue` is one of `4`, `5`, `1`.